# Autocorrelation of exponential to the power of Wiener-noise

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I want to find the autocorrelation $\langle x(t)x(t+\tau)\rangle$ of the following stochastic function

$$
x(t) = e^{-\beta W(t)}W(t)
$$

I have so far

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x(t)x(t+\tau) \rangle &= \langle (e^{-\beta W(t)}W(t))(e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)}W(t+\tau))\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W(t)}e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)})(W(t)W(t+\tau))\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W(t)}e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)})(\int_0^t dW(t)\int_0^{t+\tau}dW(t))\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W(t)}e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)})\int_0^t dW(t)(\int_0^{t}dW(t)+\int_t^{\tau}dW(t))\rangle
\end{align}
$$

From here on I am quite lost on what to do with the exponentials. Do I Taylor-expand them, or what is the best thing to do?

Comment: This is not hard. In order to compute $E x(t) x(t+\tau)$, just write $W(t+\tau) = W(t) + (W(t+\tau)-W(t))$ and use the fact that the increments of $W$ are independent. Can you write your own answer now?

Comment: @Tom Using the fact that increments of $W$ are independent, I end up having to evaluate a term like $\langle e^{-\beta W(t)}e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)} W(t)^2 \rangle$. My problem is how to do this. What do I do with the exponentials?

Comment: You might have already lost one piece. Start like this: In $e^{-\beta W_t} e^{-\beta W_{t+\tau}} W_t W_{t+\tau}$, replace *every* $W_{t+\tau}$ by $W_t + (W_{t+\tau} - W_t)$.

Comment: Then, show me your progress. Possibly by starting to write a tentative answer.

Comment: @Tom Please see my answer below. Is this the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I get based on @Tom's comments:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x(t)x(t+\tau) \rangle &= \langle (e^{-\beta W(t)}W(t))(e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)}W(t+\tau))\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W(t)}e^{-\beta W(t+\tau)})(W(t)W(t+\tau))\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_{t+\tau}})W_tW_{t+\tau}\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta (W_t + W_{t+\tau} - W_t)})W_t(W_t + W_{t+\tau} - W_t)\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta (W_t + \delta W_{t})})W_t(W_t + \delta W_{t})\rangle \\
&= \langle (e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta \delta W_{t}})W_t(W_t + \delta W_{t})\rangle \\
&= \langle e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta \delta W_{t}}W_tW_t\rangle + \langle e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta \delta W_{t}} W_t\delta W_{t}\rangle \\
&= \langle e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t}W_tW_t\rangle \langle e^{-\beta \delta W_{t}}\rangle + \langle e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t} W_t
\rangle\langle e^{-\beta \delta W_{t}}\delta W_{t}\rangle \\
&= \int{e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t}W_tW_t \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-W^2/2t}dW} \times \int{e^{-\beta \delta W_{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \tau}}e^{-\delta W^2/2\tau}d(\delta W)} + \ldots \\
\end{align}
$$

Looking at the first term

$$
\begin{align}
\int{e^{-\beta W_t}e^{-\beta W_t}W_tW_t \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-W^2/2t}dW} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int{W^2 e^{-W^2/2t -2\beta W}dW} \\
&= \frac{e^{-\beta \sqrt{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int{W^2 e^{-(W/\sqrt{2t} + \beta\sqrt{2t})^2}dW} 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: There s a problem.. Once you have $W_{t+\tau} - W_t$, NEVER break it down anymore, otherwise you destroy everything you ve done :)

Comment: Call it $\Delta W_t$ if you want.. so that you make sure you cannot break it into pieces.

Comment: @Tom I fixed that part now. What do you think, how to proceed with the exponentials?

Comment: Ok good. Split the thing in two terms (ie do that sum). Then use the fact that $\delta W_t$ is independent of $W_t$ and has a Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\tau$

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I've split the sum and used that their independent now. But still unsure how I evaluate the averages, in particular the exponentials?

Comment: Ok. you re almost there. You know the density of $W_t$ and that of $\deltaW_t$, so it boils down to evaluate some integrals. Can you do them?

Comment: @Tom I wrote the integrals for the first terms in the sum. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Apart from a type where you write $w$ instead of $2$, they re fine. The point is: can you compute them?

Comment: @Tom I would have to use Mathematica for that. Or is there a trick I don't know about?

Comment: complete the square in the exponent

Comment: @Tom Does it look better now?

Comment: If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, then $E[e^{aZ}]=e^{a^2/2}$, $E[Ze^{aZ}]=-ae^{a^2/2}$, $E[Z^2e^{aZ}]=(1+a^2)e^{a^2/2}$.

Comment: @JGWang Are we in front of the author of Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus?